# How to run Symfony with a read-only var/cache

Tags: docker, symfony, caching, symfony5

When running Symfony 5 on a **read-only** filesystem, with caches pre-generated, everything seems to work. But there are various log entries like these:

```
15:29:11 WARNING   [cache] Failed to save key "%5BApp%5CEntity%5CAddress%5C%24GEDMO_TIMESTAMPABLE_CLASSMETADATA%5D%5B1%5D" of type array: fopen(/code/var/cache/prod/pools/VPOqRtOijV/82b6c3d711e9): failed to open stream: Permission denied ["key" => "%5BApp%5CEntity%5CAddress%5C%24GEDMO_TIMESTAMPABLE_CLASSMETADATA%5D%5B1%5D","exception" => ErrorException { …},"cache-adapter" => "Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpFilesAdapter"]
15:29:11 WARNING   [cache] Failed to save key "App__Entity__Address__CLASSMETADATA__" of type Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata: fopen(/code/var/cache/prod/pools/VPOqRtOijV/82b6c3d711e9): failed to open stream: Permission denied ["key" => "App__Entity__Address__CLASSMETADATA__","exception" => ErrorException { …},"cache-adapter" => "Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\PhpFilesAdapter"]
```

Caches are pre-generated in the Dockerfile with:

```
ARG APP_ENV=prod
RUN bin/console cache:warmup
```

Is anything else necessary to run Symfony with a **read-only** var/cache directory?

Comment: There is actually a fairly lively discussion on github on this.  As far as I can tell no final solution has been merged yet.  In 5.3 there is a Kernel::getBuildDir intended for 'compilied' read-only stuff.  By default it points to /var/cache but you could experiment and see what happens if you point it to /build.  But you will probably end up need to configure your cache pools to point somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

From [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html):

> - The var/cache/ directory must be writable by the terminal user (the
>   user running cache:warmup or cache:clear commands);
> - The var/cache/
>   directory must be writable by the web server user if you use a
>   [filesystem-based cache](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/filesystem_adapter.html).

PhpFilesAdapter needs a writable var/cache/ directory.

Comment: var/cache (or all possible filesystem) should be read-only on production systems for security (https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/144). The question is how to configure it without warnings.

Comment: From [Symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/cache/adapters/php_files_adapter.html) :
`// the main cache directory (the application needs read-write permissions on it)`